# Generated EXE file from my javaFX project is not working properly

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

Exe file is created with the artifact build settings of Intellij IDEA ide.

I use multiple libraries in my project and one of them is JSoup. All of my libraries are linked by just jar files, not maven or gradle.

There are two problems that behave in the generated EXE file:

**1.. Code simply stops running when reaching JSoup code, no error or whatsoever, it just stops:**

```
System.out.println("test1"); // outputs test1
Elements rawnames = new Elements(); // Elements is a class from the JSoup library
System.out.println("test2"); // doesnt output and code from this point and after doesnt get executed
Elements rawaddresses = new Elements();
Elements rawtelephones = new Elements();
Elements rawwebsites = new Elements();
```

**2.. Some labels have bigger font size and also different padding in the EXE than when running it normally in the IDE.**

When I run my application in the IDE, everything runs perfect.

**Note: First issue also happens when tested at a runnable JAR file instead of EXE, but the second issue doesnt happen in the runnable JAR file.**

EDIT: the code above is run in a try block, this is the catch block

```
catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Platform.runLater(() -> updateLoadMsg("No internet connection.", MsgType.FAIL));
            }
```

Also worth noting that all the code I listed is being run in a Task, so the program is using multithreading.

Comment: Is that code inside a `try` block?  If so, what does the corresponding `catch` block look like?

Comment: Which is the JSoup code?  `Elements`?

Comment: @SteveSmith  it is stated in the comments. But yes Elements is the jsoup code

Comment: @VGR yes it is, I edited my post.

Comment: Are you sure you’re not getting an exception?

Comment: @VGR Yes nothing happens, nothing appears in the console of my IDE except the test system.out.println("test1") that I showed in the post.

Comment: So you’re seeing both `test1` and `test2` in your output?

Comment: @VGR I am only seeing test1 in my output

Comment: Can you give a more detailed description of the .exe creation? Also do you use the same JDK/JRE in IntelliJ and your Operating system? Many Linux distributions use OpenJDK while IntelliJ uses OracleJDK, which can lead to strange behaviour.

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA comes with some own JDK and can be switched to the locally installed one. But for any further debugging, some reproducable project is required! http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I gave up on javaFX, it is so frustrating. I decided to rewrite my program in C# WPF. Cheers.